# Discord bot only reacting to only a few commands

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been trying to figure out how to make a discord bot for my server. I started out simple with just basic reactions, but its not reacting to the other half of the commands I have given it. here is the code if anyone would like to help me with this. Keep in mind that im just a beginner and this is my very first project ever. Also these are very funny commands so be warned.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'RETRACTED';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Im alive whore');

    bot.user.setActivity ("owo");
});

const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on ("message", (message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (msg.includes ("pp")) {
        message.channel.sendMessage ("haha you said pp!")
    }

    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (msg.startsWith ("good morning")) {
        message.channel.send("Good morning! Remember to stay hydrated!")
    }

    if (msg.includes ("komaeda"))
        message.react ('');    
    }      
))

bot.on ("message", (message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (msg.includes ("eggs")) {
    message.react ('');  
    message.channel.sendMessage ("SunnySideup please")
    }

    if (msg.includes ("Jojo good")) {
    message.channel.sendMessage("Your opinion is WRONG!")
    }

    if (msg.startsWith ("Jojo")) {
    message.channel.sendMessage("jojo is bad ah ha ha")
    }
}))

bot.on ("message", (message => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (msg.includes ("Like scoob what's your favorite thing to do on the weekened")) {
        message.channel.sendMessage("Arururururururururu")
    }

    if (msg.includes ("Bathroom time")) {
        message.channel.sendMessage("Piss? Yummy!")
    }

    if (msg.includes ("Bathroom time")) {
        message.channel.sendMessage("Piss? Yummy!")
    }
}))

bot.login (token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're registering three separate `message` event listeners when `Client` only recognizes one of these.

Combine all of your `message` event listeners into on `.on("message", ...)` command and it should work fine.

Comment: @Weeblo have you had a chance to try out this solution?